# no matter what i do, when i add the modifier to the characters strength it keeps saying it isnt defined how do i fix it?

Tags: python

```
import time
import random

c1_strength = 12
c1_skill = 22
c2_strength = 16
c2_skill = 12

Modifier_skill = int(c1_skill) - int(c2_skill)
print("The skill modifier equals:\n")
print (Modifier_skill)
time.sleep(0.5)

Modifier_strength = int(c2_strength) - int(c1_strength)
print("The strength modifier equals:\n")
print (Modifier_strength)
time.sleep(0.5)

Player_1 = (random.randint(1,6))
print("Player_1 has rolled a 6 sided dice and rolled a:\n")
print(Player_1)

Player_2 = (random.randint(1,6))
print("Player_2 has rolled a 6 sided dice and rolled a:\n")
print(Player_2)

while(Player_1) == (Player_2):
    print("no changes will be made")
    break

if (Player_1) > (Player_2):
    p1_strength = int(c1_strength) + int(Modifier_strength)
print("Player_1's new strength is:\n")
print(p1_strength)

p1_skill = int(c1_skill) + int(Modifier_skill)
print("Player_1's new skill is:\n")
print(p1_skill)

p2_strength = int(c2_strength) - int(Modifier_strength)
print("Player_2's new strength is:\n")
print(p2_strength)

p2_skill = int(c2_skill) - int(Modifier_skill)
print("Player_2's new skill is:\n")
print(p2_skill)

if (Player_1) > (Player_2):
    pl2_strength = int(c2_strength) + int(Modifier_strength)
print("Player_1's new strength is:\n")
print(pl2_strength)

pl2_skill = int(c2_skill) + int(Modifier_skill)
print("Player_1's new skill is:\n")
print(pl2_skill)

pl1_strength = int(c1_strength) - int(Modifier_strength)
print("Player_2's new strength is:\n")
print(pl1_strength)

pl1_skill = int(c1_skill) - int(Modifier_skill)
print("Player_2's new skill is:\n")
print(pl1_skill)
```

this is my code, not sure whats wrong but when run it keeps saying that p1 strength is not defined. Another strange thing is that sometimes the code will work once or twice but then the next part will create an error, then after somehow fixing that the first part breaks again

Comment: What language is that? Python?

Comment: What language is this code in? Tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Because `p1_strength` only exists `if (Player_1) == (Player_2)`. If Player_1 and Player_2 are not equal, the variable is never declared and the line trying to `print(p1_strength)` will fail.

Comment: Why all those calls to `int`? The values are integers already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm barely sure what is even going on. this is hideous python. the problem is that p1_strength is defined in the if block

```
if(Player_1 > Player_2):
    p1_strength = int(c1_strength) + int(Modifier_strength)
```

if this block does not execute, i.e. if Player_1 <= Player_2, p1_strength will be undefined.

this can be fixed by initializing your variables in the top of your script with something for instance, 0

```
c1_strength = 12
c1_skill = 22
c2_strength = 16
c2_skill = 12
p1_strength = 0
pl2_strength = 0
```